# deciphering an array of objects in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have an array of objects I am passing from my servlet to the jsp

I have my own class called `object` located at  `com.example`

```
class object {

String param1;

//getters and setters

}
```

my servlet code:

```
object[] sampleObject = new object[5];

// code to populate object 

RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("/inc/example.jsp"); 
request.setAttribute("object", sampleObject);
dispatch.forward(request, response);
```

my `example.jsp`

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
 <%@ page import="com.example.object" %>
    <jsp:useBean id="object" scope="request" class="java.util.Arrays" />

     <%
     int l = object.length;
    %>
```

this fails with the error `The value for the useBean class attribute java.lang.Arrays is invalid`

when I tried

```
<jsp:useBean id="object" scope="request" class="com.example.object" />
```

the error I get is

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to object
```

It still fails . how should I be configuring my jsp to use this .

what should be my class defined in the jsp:useBean  for the object . it shouts at me for choosing java.util.Arrays as invalid but also shouts at me when I use com.example.object

Comment: Instead of your `<%...%>` (called scriptlet, should -almost- never be used), try `${object.length}` (expression language, EL).

Comment: Assuming that one of your getters is "getLength()" then why are you using `object.length` instead of `object.getLength()`?

Comment: @Chad No I have no getters for the length , only for the params I have inside the class

Comment: Well your object class does not have a "length" if you do not set/get it. I think you need to add a getter/setter for length, then when you create sampleObject, you can set the length, and call `getLength()` in your jsp file in place of `object.length`.

Comment: @Chad , I have a more fundamental problem at this point , what should be my class defined in the <jsp:useBean  for the object . it shouts at me for choosing java.util.Arrays as invalid but also shouts at me when I use com.example.object

Comment: Using `<jsp:useBean id="object" scope="request" class="com.example.object.object" />` should work, as long as your object class is located in your com.example.object folder. It goes to com.example.object and then looks for object, so you may need an extra ".object".

Comment: Naming a class "object" is extremely confusing.

Comment: @Chad , object is located under the com.example so that seems fine

Comment: Then your sentence "object located at com.example.object" should be "object located at com.example".

Comment: my apologies for the mixup

Comment: Could you update your question with the exact error you are getting? If you are correct and your file is named object under com.example then what you have should be correct, at least for the `<jsp:useBean />`

Comment: @Chad , updated with the error

Comment: Okay, that is telling you that it is looking for an array (because you store an array of 5 objects). However, your class is a single object, not an array. Why are you trying to store an array of objects anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="object" scope="request" class="java.lang.Object" />
```

At least you will be able to get the array, then use explicit casting to get the specific attributes. But better use EL tags to iterate through the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

Create an object with a length of 5, not an array of 5 objects.

So add a length attribute to your class:

```
class object {

    String param1;
    int length;

    //getters and setters
    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
    public int getLength() {
        return this.length;
    }

}
```

Now, you can create your new object and set its length.

```
 object sampleObject = new object();
 sampleObject.setLength(5);
```

And finally, you can call it from your jsp page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.example.object" %>
<jsp:useBean id="object" scope="request" class="com.example.object" />

<% int l = object.getLength(); %>
```